# In Notepad++, I've lost the document-switcher offscreen (I think). How do I get it back?

Tags: notepad++, window

I know how to disable and enable the document switcher in preferences. But doing that has no visible effect, and I strongly suspect the panel is offscreen. How do I get a hold of it to move it? Many people have experienced the same problem with the find window, but this seems trickier because there's no command I know to give the doc switcher focus.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this myself by editing the configuration file.

http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Editing_Configuration_Files

One of the FloatingWindow elements had a negative width plus a negative position value, and I presumed it was the culprit and made both positive.

Comment: Please add the XML configuration that you've change or added. It'll help readers :)

Answer (score 0):

Editing the configuration like described by [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1420880/693358) actually didn't work for me. But connecting a second monitor, putting the Notepad window there and then disconnecting the monitor (so that all windows are moved to the notebook screen) solved it. The DocSwitcher Window then appeared in the visible area again.